# What is the cardinality of the set of normal numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

And in general, what else can we say about the set of normal numbers?
We know that a normal number must be irrational, and hence it is possible that the set of normal numbers is countable or uncountable, since the irrational numbers are uncountable. I have been unable to find much literature or research about this topic.

Comment: Almost every real number (in the sense of Lebesgue measure) is normal.  A set of positive Lebesgue measure has cardinality $c$.

Comment: I suppose that by "normal" you mean absolutely normal. If you just mean normal in base ten, it is trivial that there are continuum many normal numbers if there is one, since you can alter a "thin" set of its decimal digits at will without affecting normality.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number

Comment: Verónica Becher authors a fair number of papers about normal and absolutely normal numbers. Google should get you PDFs of many of them.